# IOS - When Slider Value Changed Set UILabel Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I want to set label when uislider changed but When I set the label in valueChanged, the screen freezes or the parentview disappears.

```
    @IBAction func changedSliderValue(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let value = Int(sliderExtraRepeat.value)
    if lastSliderValue != value {
        self.labelExtraRepeat.text = String(value) + " tekrar daha gelirdi."
        print(String(format: "%.0f", self.sliderExtraRepeat.value))
        lastSliderValue = value
    }
}
```

When I comment on the line with the label, the slider can be moved smoothly. Although I struggled for hours, I could not figure out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is it totally necessary to have a global variable 'lastSliderValue'?
If not, it is recommended to remove the global variable as a whole.

Try this.

```
    @IBAction func changedSliderValue(_ sender: UISlider) {

// 1. make sure 'Int(sliderExtraRepeat.value)' does not return a value between 0 to 1 
    let value = Int(sliderExtraRepeat.value) 

//2. try this instead.
    labelExtraRepeat.text = String(value) + " tekrar daha gelirdi."

//3. make sure you set UISlider.isContinuous = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the UI on the main thread? Like this:-

```
@IBAction func changedSliderValue(_ sender: UISlider) {
  let value = Int(sliderExtraRepeat.value)
  if lastSliderValue != value {

      DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.labelExtraRepeat.text = String(value) + " tekrar daha gelirdi."
      }
      
      print(String(format: "%.0f", self.sliderExtraRepeat.value))
      lastSliderValue = value
  }
}
```